# Swig Interface definition for pointer to opaque struct

Tags: c++, c, binding, wrapper, swig

I'm currently trying to generate language bindings for ReconstructMe SDK (http://reconstructme.net/) using SWIG. I'm trying to generate low-level bindings for Python, Java and CSharp. The API I'm trying to wrap is a plain C-API and SWIG does a good job wrapping most parts of it automatically, except for one key part.

ReconstructMe SDK declares a pointer to an opaque context object as

```
typedef struct _reme_context* reme_context_t;
```

and provides two functions that either create a new or destroy and existing one

```
// Output a new context
reme_error_t reme_context_create(reme_context_t *c);

// Destroy existing context and set pointer to null
reme_error_t reme_context_destroy(reme_context_t *c);
```

All other functions of ReMe take a `reme_context_t` object as input. For example

```
reme_error_t reme_context_compile(reme_context_t c);
```

What SWIG does by default it creates two not convertible types: one for `reme_context_t` and one for `reme_context_t*`.

What I'd like to achieve is to tell SWIG to reinterpret the `reme_context_t` as a pointer to void or something similar that it can handle in all languages and cast to `reme_context_t` where necessary.

For example in CSharp a natural way of reinterpreting the above would be to use `System.IntPtr`, so that the above turns into

```
reme_error_t reme_context_create(out System.IntPtr c);
reme_error_t reme_context_destroy(ref System.IntPtr c);
reme_error_t reme_context_compile(System.IntPtr c);
```

Is there an easy way to do this and to do it in a such a generic way that the SWIG code handles multiple languages?

Thanks in advance,
Christoph

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/a/14427814/168175 help?

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/a/12767656/168175

Comment: Hi Flexo. Thanks for the hints. Especially the first one sounds interesting. Will look into it.